# Как вывести массив чисел в TableView?

Tags: java, массивы, javafx

Есть двумерный массив чисел, его нужно вывести в `TableView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простой пример вывода содержимого двумерного массива в `TableView`:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane rootStackPane = new StackPane();
        String[][] dataArray =
                {{"First column", "Second column", "Third column", "Fourth column", "Fifth column"},
                {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5",},
                {"6", "7", "8", "9", "10",},
                {"11", "12", "13", "14", "15"}};
        ObservableList<String[]> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        observableList.addAll(Arrays.asList(dataArray));
        observableList.remove(0);
        TableView<String[]> tableView = new TableView<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray[0].length; i++) {
            TableColumn tableColumn = new TableColumn(dataArray[0][i]);
            int columnNumber = i;
            tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String[], String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String[], String> p) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty((p.getValue()[columnNumber]));
                }
            });
            tableView.getColumns().add(tableColumn);
        }
        tableView.setItems(observableList);
        rootStackPane.getChildren().add(tableView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootStackPane, 500, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Здесь `dataArray` – исходный двумерный массив.

Выглядит это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @post_zeewСпасибо